# Загрузка файла на компьютер пользователя на JS

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

Реализую web-интерфейс для онлайн обработки картинок (на canvas), столкнулся с проблемой (скорее возник вопрос реализации):
Текущий принцип работы: пользователь загружает картинку она перекодируется в **base64** и **сохраняется в localStorage**. Для скачивания измененного изображения пользователь нажимает на кнопку (по клику на нее идет ajax-запрос на сервер, который передает **картинку в base64**), через PHP я ее сохраняю на сервер, по завершению запроса идет авто-клик по ссылке типа `<a href="image.jpg" download>Download</a>`.

**Вопрос**: Могу ли я отдать файл на скачивание пользователю, без сохранения его на сервере?

Comment: Хранить картинки в localStorage - это конечно неплохо, но лучше сразу бд сделай там 

Comment: это лишь временное хранилище, что бы canvas не сбрасывал картинку при обновлении окна

Comment: скачать можно не отправляя на сервер

Comment: да, конечно, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL для ссылки, а дальше автоклик

Comment: @HTMLProgrammer, есть же https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: @Qweriy, можно и так, но там надо будет ещё создать ссылку при помощи https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь, ответ оказался элементарным:

```
  save() {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', cvs.toDataURL('image/png'));
        link.setAttribute('download', 'image.png');
        link.click();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Там есть метод для blob, у base64 ограничена длина, так что может не работать.